# Jquery function difference

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //some code here
});
```

and

```
$(function() {
    //some code here
});
```

I feel that they use for the same purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same thing: http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#callback

> A shorthand for $(document).ready().

Answer (score 1):

It's a shortcut/alias to `$(document).ready()`.

Here's something you might want to read:
[Introducing $(document).ready()](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready)